# How to generate fixtures for testing Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, tdd, actionmailer

I am thinking quite a time about how to do TDD using fixtures with ActionMailer. The main Problem is how to generate the fixtures. I want to cover the following scenarios:

1. Receiving of Plain Text Mail
2. Receiving of HTML Mail
3. Receiving of Mail with Plain Text and HTML
4. Receiving of Mail with Attachments

Another relating question is: If I've generated the fixtures I want can I just pass the content of them into the corresponding mailers receive method?

Comment: This rails guide covers a lot of that http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers

Comment: Thanks alot. Read many articles on that site, but missed this specific one.

Comment: Edit: There's no section that covers testing receiving of mails and the're is nor shown how to do html und plain text emails neither how testing with attachments.